# Is there a reason ros::param::get does not provide a float overload?

Tags: ros, parameter, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using ros::param recently I noticed with some frustration some frustration that it's seemingly impossible to pass a float reference to ros::param::get or ros::param::param both for the reason of the missing float overload.

It seems like such an odd omission that it makes me wonder if it's intentional. Anyone have any idea?

I filed a bug report here:

- https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3754

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11979/is-there-a-reason-ros::param::get-does-not-provide-a-float-overload?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This appears to be a duplicate of [my question](http://answers.ros.org/question/1899/why-cant-you-use-floats-for-accessing-parameters).

Thanks for adding the bug report!

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-11-17**:
Yep, definitely a duplicate. But, like you it seems, I'm not sure I understand the reasoning given.